# Sorting array of colors by palette

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, colors

I have the array of colors:

```
private static string[] Colors = new string[] {
    "#A2AD00", "#69963B", "#00B2C0", "#009697", "#A31A7E",
    "#7D0063", "#EEAF00", "#EC7A00", "#0097D4", "#006FB4"
};
```

How can I sort colors by palette?

Sorry for confusing question.
I want to arrange these items by color groups (greens to greens, red to reds..) and inside each group items must be arranged by color brightness.

([Link to color groups representation](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/))

Comment: As @sll said, there's no way this question can be answered constructively without knowing if you should consider reds "greater than" blues and so on.

Comment: Get R, G, B, and group by the highest. That roughly groups by primary color. For brightness, sort by grayscale (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B).

Comment: This question should have never been downvoted. I required the ability to collect palette data for my game, and ended up with some code that you might find useful(It uses GetPixel though, and is therefore not optimized): http://pastebin.com/mfSNsHKp

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the Color list instead of string array. The following sorting function sorts through the colors of the rainbow.

```
List<Color> myColors = new List<Color>();
```

add colors to the list

```
myColors.Add (new Color (r,g,b))

colors.Sort(delegate(System.Drawing.Color left, System.Drawing.Color right)
{
  return left.GetBrightness().CompareTo(right.GetBrightness ());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of strings, not colors. While those strings can be converted to color objects, you can't get a palette from that.

A palette is used in an indexed bitmap, so that an index n points to a specific Color; not the other way around. There is no conversion the other way unless you also know the indexed Bitmap from which the colors was taken.

In other words, for your question; "sorting by palette" to make any sense, you will at least need to know the [`ColorPalette`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette.aspx) object from which the colors was taken. I am guessing that you mean to sort by the index in the palette ? In that case, you can look up the colors in the Entries array to get their index; then sort by that index.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
    Array.Sort(Colors );
    foreach (string s in Colors )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```